# 80s or 90s movie about aliens that go to Earth, some without gender

Tags: story-identification, movie

While looking for a show or movie to watch. I was trying to remember the name of one from 80s or 90s. I was very young then and haven't seen it in years. But here goes:

From what I remember the movie was about aliens. I can't remember if it's on their planet or ours. One didn't have a gender and I think was running from something or someone, bald or short hair IIRC. They met a human and the one scene that sticks out is something about the alien taking off its clothes and to go swimming, and dives into water. I don't know if it was an ocean or beach.

The swimming took place at night off a cliff. At least one of the aliens was hiding or running from someone. The human was a male, I think shortish hair. He said something about the alien being beautiful when swimming. I feel like the movie was shown on US TV, probably something like HBO, or the SciFi channel. The aliens started having androgynous kids and for some reason picked humans. Something to do with that they have a hard time making kids now due to years of cloning. I think the swimmer was the first in some time to be able to have them again. The night time had a purple tint to the horizon.

Edit:
I from what I remember the special night scene in particular the cliff or ledge looked corny and cheep af, almost like it was made from from plastic and clay with a weird melted look.

I feel like it had some kind of alien only medicine, and what was probably supposed to be super hightech gizmos. But looked like a fragile cardboard or plastic case for apples and a few PC's. I don't think they showed weapons. I kind of feel like their was some kind of a space ship involved.
Edit: by long time ago: The last I saw this was was 30 years ago. I'd have been 12-14.

Edit: It's not alien nation: because those aliens get hurt by water. I just saw the TV show about 2 days ago now.
Edit:I simply don't remember seeing all of the ship. The scene of it I very badly recall at the moment was part of it. I only remember seeing the left half on the right side of the tv screen. This would be the outside. I think they meant for it to look like  it was mist or a light fog but the effect came off more like dust covering it.
I thought it was kind of hubcap shaped but covered in a bunch of random antena's and lights.

Edit:I thought the medicicine the aliens were using was because of either age or being cloned so much they had to take it to not fall appart or melt or what ever they would do.

Edit: it's not lifeforce.

Edit: I'm also pretty sure that it was live action.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F! If you'd take a look at the story identification question guidelines and add detail, it'll make it a lot easier for people to answer your question.

Comment: Welcome Gork. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways. Peter Nielson is referring to [this page](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) which might jog your memory of a few important details for us to help you.

Comment: From what i remember the diving scene took place at night. The alien wanted to have sex with the human from what I remember. I want to say the one without a gender was considered special. I think it was hiding or something. The scene I remember likely a cliff. I think it was supposed to be real but looking back was made in early CGI. I think the human did eventually get it on with the genderless one somehow.  They all spoke english to. It wasn't well produced either.  It was probably shown on american TV as well. I don't know what channel though :(

Comment: Ah thank you rogue!

Comment: Was there any alien technology involved (spacecrafts, weapons, etc)?

Comment:  I want to say their was some alien medicine and a space ship. But I'm struggling at the moment to remember if their was weapons. I think the ones that couldn't reproduce needed some sort of medicine. And now that i think about I have this hazy memory of some sort of a computer one of them used that was supposed to be futuristic but was more like an apple with a bad cut on it and just ended up looking camp AF.

Comment: Do you remember how that spaceship looked like? And what was that medicine - did they tried to cure something?

Comment:  I can't remember the ship well. I think it was covered in mist or fog. I' almost want to say the ship had a lot  stuff on the outside like rods and lights. But at the time their were a lot of weird scifi ships like that.  The medicine? yeah I think you're right that it was for a cure of some sort. :) I'm not sure what entirely. Possibly because of them being sick,fragile and or pretty old even for them. Hmm   I think that was why they picked earth because the air or something would slow down their disease.

Comment: Hmm. I think that's why they picked earth. Something about normally sterile or a genetic condition or something like that. And humans dna could help somehow?

Comment: The swimming makes me think of Coccoon or Coccoon 2. But the genderless alien makes me think of Enemy Mine.

Comment: Hmm do you know where I could find some pictures? I've tried to look on google for swimming or cliff diving  scenes, even adding purple or pink. A lot of hits of stock pictures-- and a few behind the scenes one. I think you're onto something. Do you know if either one was on TV much at the time? Hmmm it's a long shot: I wonder if it was a made for tv special.